# How to display url value of a field type of "url"

Tags: content-management-system, apostrophe

I'm using Apostrophe CMS 2 and having difficulty displaying the url value.

index.js

```
{
  type: 'url',
  name: 'cta-video',
  label: 'Call to Action Video'
},
```

widget.html

```
{{ data.widget.cta-video }}
```

Comment: Can you explain a little more regarding the difficulty you are having?

Comment: The URL type makes sure there is http:// etc. In the widget I can't have it display the value of the url.